# SQLAlchemy ORM autoloading with relationships

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have made a table from one service (not using sqlalchemy), and now i want to query the tables using sqlalchemy

i used a syntax like this

```py
from app import db, engine, Base
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, String, Integer, TIMESTAMP, Float


class Post(Base):
    __table__ = Table('posts', Base.metadata,
                      autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
```

And this is working, i can query my objects.

The annoyance is, that i can't get the properties before runtime, because (obviously), there is nothing before it compiles. Is there a way to add the types when using something like this, or do i have to assume, that they are there?

Comment: Well, you could hard-code the appropriate `Column` objects in your class based on your knowledge of the table structure, but what's the problem with just reflecting them the way you do now and then just "assume that [the columns] are there"?

Comment: BTW, `autoload=True` is obsolete; just use `autoload_with=engine`

Comment: @GordThompson thanks for the hint! I guess it's not a problem. What about relationships though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For existing tables we can reflect the table-specific information (columns, FKs, etc.) and still add our own extra ORM-specific attributes like relationships:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

print(sa.__version__)  # 1.3.20
connection_uri = "mssql+pyodbc://@mssqlLocal64"
engine = sa.create_engine(connection_uri, echo=False)

# show existing sample data
with engine.connect() as conn:
    results = conn.execute(sa.text("SELECT * FROM users"))
    print([dict(r) for r in results])
    # [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Gord'}]
    results = conn.execute(sa.text("SELECT * FROM posts"))
    print([dict(r) for r in results])
    # [{'id': 1, 'user_id': 1, 'post': 'Hello world!'}]

Base = declarative_base()
meta = Base.metadata


class User(Base):
    __table__ = sa.Table("users", meta, autoload_with=engine)


class Post(Base):
    __table__ = sa.Table("posts", meta, autoload_with=engine)
    author = sa.orm.relationship("User")

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Post(id={self.id}, author_name='{self.author.name}', post='{self.post}')>"


Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

my_post = session.query(Post).get(1)
print(my_post)  # <Post(id=1, author_name='Gord', post='Hello world!')>
```

Comment: In terms of performance i only have three relationships. So fair i have just done manually filtering
`author = ....
 book = session.query(Book).filter(author_id = author.id)
` 

Is this a bad practise in terms of implementing it in the way you demonstrated?